# Submit multiple form data to more than one model ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

In my web application I am using one view (`Create.cshtml`) to display two different forms which post data to separate models. The form which you can see implemented on the Create page is posting to the `Check` model. The other form is rendered as a partial view - the user clicks a button, and on each click, the form is added to the page - this one posts to the `CheckFolders` model.

The idea, is that a 'Check' contains 'CheckFolders'. A user can create one Check, with many CheckFolders. When both forms are submitted, the ID of the newly created check, should be added to each CheckFolder `(CheckId)`.

The problem I am facing is posting the data of both forms to their relevant models - and submitting more than one CheckFolder form at once.

**Create.cshtml:**

```
@model Application_Support_Dashboard.Models.Check

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CheckId);
    Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ScheduleId); }

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Check</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NTO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NTO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateScheduledOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateScheduledOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateScheduledOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCompletedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCompletedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCompletedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScheduleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="divPartial">
            <!-- Partial views appear here-->
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="AddFolderCheck" value="Add new Item" />

        <script>
            $("#AddFolderCheck").click(function (e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'AddNewFolderCheck',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify('@Model'),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (partialview) {
                            $('#divPartial').append(partialview);
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>

        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> }

<input type='number' size='10' id='numberinput' name='mynumber' value='0' step="1" />

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

**_PartialCheckFolderModel:**

```
@model Application_Support_Dashboard.Models.CheckFolder

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FolderName)</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FolderName" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfFiles)</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="NumberOfFiles" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilesResolved)</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="FilesResolved" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All data is to be inserted into the SQL Database (Application_Support_DashboardContext).

Sorry if I haven't provided enough information/code - please let me know if so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cant submit more than one form at once. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options as to how to dynamically add collection items to a model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, I will look into these!

Comment: That's a whole lot of code to wade through - perhaps have a read of this: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)